# Best way to print a balanced BST in random order?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal, random-access, avl-tree

I'm sorry if this seems like a random question, but I have a database of over 100,000 name/value pairs (call them high scores, if you will) stored in a balanced binary search tree, AVL-style.  Most of time, to list the scores, I print the BST with an in-order traversal or reverse-order traversal, but today I came across a need for printing the tree in random (or pseudorandom) order.  Is there some accepted or optimal way of doing this: visit every node exactly once, but in an unpredictable fashion?

PS -- I thought about a breadth-first traversal, but since that always happens in the same way, it's not really random.  There has to be some clever way, or some ideal interview answer, since this seems like a common problem; I just haven't come up with anything really clever outside of just marking nodes as visited, or creating an external tracking data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the answer to this isn't just taking the BST, linearizing it, and then print it out.  I suppose that your concern here is that linearizing a data structure such as this may take a lot of memory.  If this is the case, you can always pick out *pieces* of the tree, linearize them, and then jump around.  Traversing pointers randomly and hoping for an ordering that will work well is a bad idea: you're always going to get screwed looking for the last node.  If you have a *complete* binary tree, you can always come up with numbers and start from the root (essentially, you get the linearization for free from the completeness property of the tree).

EDIT:

I was less informed than I perhaps should be, because I recently discovered this article, though it's based on a functional implementation, it may be of use to you.  I haven't read it all, so I don't know how it works for iterating through everything, but if you simply want to get a single node out, then you can use this..

http://okmij.org/ftp/Algorithms.html#random-tree-node

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Right, I guess I haven't thought enough about my linearization algorithm.  Do you just generate a bunch of random left traversals and right traversals until you uniquely cover them all?  I know how to generate a random ordering of indices from 1:size, but it looks like this is boiling down to how I can convert a single index into a tree traversal.

Comment: By linearize I mean go through the tree using a standard traversal, stick them in a list, and then randomize the list.  You will be doing something similarly equivalent using any algorithm, even if in a lazy fashion, if implemented by a variation on random pointer chases you get something roughly equivalent to passing thunks around with bounds on the search space that is visited.

Comment: I understand... but, sort of changing my question, because standard traversal is O(n), I wonder if we could have some indexing algorithm that allows us random access O(1).  Of course, printing all elements in random order would still require the complete linearization, as you wrote, but the additional step of preassigning indices 1-size to each node might require fewer operations for a set number of accesses.  Sorry, I realize that does change the question a bit.  This comment would apply only if we wanted n < N random draws.  Say we need 1 random draw.  Listing all seems like overkill.

Comment: Generate a random binary number, start at the root, and look at each bit, when you see a 0 go left and when you see a 1 go right.  This will give you somewhat random behavior (when you try to go right and can't, just stay at the node, and you also need to stay at intermediate nodes with some probability..)